# Problemas con el header

Tags: html, python, css, flask

Tengo este problema con el header:
[image]

Los div (o container) quedan así. Intenté ponerle padding top pero si agrego otros div/container vuelven a subir quedando en este resultado y yo quiero que queden abajo de la barra de búsqueda y no como esta ahora en la imagen.

El header (barra de búsqueda) cuando haga scroll hacia abajo se quedara en en el lugar fijo, NO acompañaría hacia abajo como acá por ejemplo que el logo y la barra bajan.

El buscador lo uní con el header porque sino quedaba mas desastroso y creo es mejor que el buscador este dentro del header

Este es el código:

```css
header{
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
}

.otro{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

h2{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.Buscar input{
    width: 800px;
    height: 40px;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid silver;
    border-radius: 30px;
}


.Buscar{
    width: 800px ;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 10 40px 10 25px;
    position: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 6px;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #1379bd;
}

.contenedor{ 
    padding-top: 105vh;
    display: flex;
}

.contenedor2{   
    display: flex;
}

.contenedor3{
    display: flex;
}

.card{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 20px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px rgb(0,0,0,0.2);
    cursor: default;
    transition: all 400ms ease;
}

.card:hover{
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px rgb(0,0,0,0.4);
    transform: translateY(-3%);
}

.card img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 210px;
}

.card .contenido{
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

.card .contenido p{
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #6a6a6a;
}

.card .contenido h3{
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.card .contenido a{
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: #2fb4cc;
    border: 1px solid #2fb4cc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    transition: all 400ms ease;
}

.card .contenido a:hover{
    background: #2fb4cc;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<body> 
  <header>
    
    <h2>Pagina</h2>
  
  

  <div class="otro">
    <div class="Buscar">
      <form action="#" method="get">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Ingrese una Categoria" name="search">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  </header> 

  <div class="contenedor">    
      <div class="card">
        <figure>
          <img src="../static/imag2.jpg">
        </figure>
        <div class="contenido">
          
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia, nihil!</p>
          <a href="-"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="card">
        <figure>
          <img src="../static/ouch.jpg">
        </figure>
        <div class="contenido">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia, nihil!</p>
          <a href="-"></a>
        </div>
      </div>    
  </div>
```

Los otros div son iguales a estos 2, porque hice copia y pega, asi que no los puse.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema? Para ti será lógico, pero el resto no sabe cuál es. ¿Podrías especificarlo? Aparte, 'padding-top:105vh' quiere decir que el valor del padding es el 105% del alto de la pagina, vamos que si la pantalla tiene 1000px por ejemplo le estas indicando que sea 1050

Comment: Buenas lo siento, ahí lo corregí, básicamente que los container/div se mantengan abajo del header (de la barra de búsqueda), al padding lo agregue solo para probar algo así que no es relevante,

Comment: Yo creo que si elminias el position absolute y top 20px del header y le añades un padding-top: lo que sea, ya te deberían de aparecer abajo

Comment: Tienes que eliminar el `position: absolute` de la clase header. Además tienes que eliminar el `height:100vh` del body, que hace que se comporte raro cuando tienes bastantes imágenes

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya funciono, era eso